# How can I find the arn of an api gateway stage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, tagging

I am trying to use awscli to add tags to my api gateway stage
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/tag-resource.html

I am required to supply the `--resource-arn` for the stage, however I am unable to ascertain this value.

I have tried using both awscli and the console to determine this value, but have been unable to find what the arn for the api gateway stage is.  I have also tried guessing based off arn pattern/formats.

How can I determine this value, or alternatively what is the format for this arn?

Comment: Have you checked out this page?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-apigateway

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I finally found the format for an api gateway stage at [aws docs for set up tags via the API Gateway REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html).

The format for the ARN is `arn:aws:apigateway:{region}::/restapis/{rest_api_id}/stages/{stage_name}`

Comment: An edit was put to refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-apigateway
I had already look at this page and it lacks the detail that I needed to determine the ARN

Comment: Just had to figure this out, this is the only place I can find with the actual answer. I see nothing in AWS docs explaining why you need the `/restapis` and `/stages` strings in the ARN, plus you must leave out the account ID. A life saver...

Comment: I actually found that it worked with the account id.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/arn-format-reference.html
Only API Gate way specific ARN formats

Comment: the AWS docs are frustratingly unclear at times :<

Comment: New info with help on this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/easily-protect-your-aws-cdk-defined-infrastructure-with-aws-wafv2/

Comment: Every other service I use has a templated page with a header section giving many details always including the ARN with a little copy icon that you can click to copy the ARN to the clipboard. But API Gateway? No, we're special. We're different. We're *better*.

Answer (score 1):

At the very bottom there are samples for different APIGW artifacts, last one is stage.

*arn:aws:apigateway:region::/restapis/api-id/stages/stage-name*

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-create-and-manage-api.html

Comment: That link now redirects to the developer guide welcome page. Possibly this link may be the kind of content that was intended and is more useful now at any rate: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/arn-format-reference.html