# Add a tag to aws api gateway using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, rest

I am trying to add a tag to an existing restApi with aws cli.

Have tried

`aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id ${rest_api_id} --patch-operations op=add,path=/tags/keytest,value='testvalue'`

and getting

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateRestApi operation: Invalid patch path /tags/keytest
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `tag-resource` method instead of `update-rest-api`

> `aws apigateway tag-resource --resource-arn your-api-gateway-arn --tags tag-name=tag-value`

The arn format of api gateway can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514180/how-can-i-find-the-arn-of-an-api-gateway-stage/48532146)

Edit: this will update the stage tag.